# What is the declaration that need to use when using HashMap <String,Drawable>?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

Currently I'm doing a task that involves `HashMap`. And what I'm doing right now is to insert 3 variable in the `HashMap`. I succeed to make it but there is the error regarding the syntax or declaration (I don't know which one). Can someone help me detect what wrong with my syntax/declaration and come up with a solution? Below is my code:

```
public static void showAVMode(Context context, String AVMode) {
    mContext = context;
    spotText = getAvModeText(AVMode);
    spotType= "";
    call_Spot=3000;
    if(mContext != null) {
        spotType=mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_name);
        currentSpot=5;
        show();
    } else {
        TvLog.d(TAG, "context is null");
    }
}
```

.............................

```
private static String getAvModeText(String mode){
    String avMode = mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_stand);

    HashMap<String,Drawable> AvModeIconTHX = new HashMap<String,Drawable>();
    AvModeIconTHX.put(mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_movTHX), mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.set_thx));

    HashMap<String,Drawable> AvModeIconES = new HashMap<String,Drawable>();
    AvModeIconES.put(mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_stand), mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.set_es));

    HashMap<String,Drawable> AvModeMovie = new HashMap<String,Drawable>();
    AvModeMovie.put(mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_mov), null);
    HashMap<String,Drawable> AvModeGame = new HashMap<String,Drawable>();
    AvModeGame.put(mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_game), null);
    HashMap<String,Drawable> AvModePC = new HashMap<String,Drawable>();
    AvModePC.put(mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_PC), null);
    HashMap<String,Drawable> AvModeUser = new HashMap<String,Drawable>();
    AvModeUser.put(mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_user), null);
    HashMap<String,Drawable> AvModeDyn = new HashMap<String,Drawable>();
    AvModeDyn.put(mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_dyn), null);
    HashMap<String,Drawable> AvModeDynFix = new HashMap<String,Drawable>();
    AvModeDynFix.put(mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_dynFix), null);

    HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Drawable>> mapAvMode = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Drawable>>();
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVMode.AVMODE_STANDARD, AvModeIconES);
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVMode.AVMODE_MOVIE, AvModeMovie);
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVMode.AVMODE_MOVIE_THX, AvModeIconTHX);
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVMode.AVMODE_GAME, AvModeGame);
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVMode.AVMODE_PC, AvModePC);
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVMode.AVMODE_CUSTOM, AvModeUser);
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVMode.AVMODE_DYNAMIC, AvModeDyn);
    mapAvMode.put(TvFunctionID.AVMode.AVMODE_DYNAMIC_FIXED, AvModeDynFix);

    if(mapAvMode.containsKey(mode)) {
        avMode = mapAvMode.get(mode);
    }
    return avMode;
```

}

the error is at the code `mapAvMode.get(mode);` where it says `Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<String,Drawable> to String`. There is the quickfix but it didn't solve the error. Can someone help me with this? And I think my code can be much shorter than this. Any suggestion would greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Your avMode variable is a type `String` while the object return by mapAvMode is `HashMap<String,Drawable>`. In a HashMap, the first parameter is the key (here String) and the second is the value (here Drawable). If you want to get the String value from this HashMap, you should do : `avMode = mapAvMode.get(mode).get(yourParam);`

**Update** : sorry, I gave a wrong information. So I'm correcting my answer. `mapAvMode.get(mode)` will return a `HashMap<String, Drawable>` and if you write this :

`mapAvMode.get(mode).get(yourParam);`.

It will return a Drawable. So your avMode variable must be either a HashMap and this line will work :

`avMode = mapAvMode.get(mode)`

or it must be a Drawable and this line will work:

`avMode = mapAvMode.get(mode).get(yourParam);`

Answer (score 0):

```
`mapAvMode.get(mode)`
```

returns a drawable that you are type casting to String change your avMode to drawable it will solve your problem,`HashMap.get(key)`is used to get the value on the basis of the key you passed,here our value is drawable.